# Equivalent of SQL Server choose and string_split in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've optimized a SQL Server procedure recently. Went from this

```
select id, 'col1' as valtype, col1 as val from table1 where col1 > 0
union all
select id, 'col2', col2 from table1 where col2 > 0
union all
select id, 'col3', col3 from table1 where col3 > 0
```

to this:

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
         id, valtype,
         case valtype
             when 'col1' then col1
             when 'col2' then col2
             when 'col3' then col3
         end as val
     from 
         table1 
     cross join 
         (VALUES ('col1'), ('col2'), ('col3')) t(valtype)
    ) a 
where 
    val > 0
```

to this:

```
select * 
from 
    (select 
         id, value as valtype,
         choose(ordinal, col1, col2, col3) as val
     from 
         table1
     cross join 
         string_split('col1,col2,col3', ',', 1) t
    ) a 
where val > 0
```

So how would I go about this progression in Postgres?

Is there an equivalent function to `CHOOSE` other than `CASE`?

Is there a `string_to_array` that also returns index?

Comment: You've asked two totally different questions here, which is inappropriate. What happens when (as has already occurred) a user answers one of the questions, and then a different user answers the other one? Which answer do you accept as correct, and how do you explain punishing the other answerer by not choosing their answer instead? The site guidelines allow a single question per post for that exact reason. If you have two separate questions, they need to be in two separate posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find the `choose()` function convenient and desirable, you can easily create it in Postgres:

```sql
create or replace function choose(bigint, variadic anyarray)
returns anyelement language sql immutable as $$
    select $2[$1]
$$;
```

Instead of `string_split()` use `string_to_table() with ordinality`:

```sql
select * 
from (
    select 
        id, value as valtype,
        choose(ordinal, col1, col2, col3) as val
    from table1
    cross join string_to_table('col1,col2,col3', ',') with ordinality as t(value, ordinal)
    ) a 
where val > 0
order by 1, 2
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/5hL7AWQn)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a postgresql equivalent of `CHOOSE()`, however something like `string_split` can be done with `unnest with ordinality` and `string_to_array` like follows:

```
select * from (
  select id, valtype,
    case valtype
      when 'col1' then col1
      when 'col2' then col2
      when 'col3' then col3
    end as val
  from table1
  cross join unnest(string_to_array('col1,col2,col3', ',') ) WITH ORDINALITY a(valtype, nr)
) a where val > 0
```